# Communication with worker roles in windows azure

Tags: azure, communication, worker, role, azure-role-environment

I present my problem if anyone can help will be appreciated:

I have a web site (implemented in WebForms in Azure) where the user can make configurations that will result into a XML with all the data of the configuration.
In the other hand, I have a Worker Role which is working and need this XML configuration.

The question is: how can I send this XML file generated by the user to the Worker Role?

I have looked for something similar to a REST API as interol communication seems not to be the correct path to follow.

Comment: Have you looked at [Azure Queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/)?

Comment: I have read they have bad performance issues, the likes of taking up to twenty minutes to process messages. If it is not a problem anymore (the application needs real time response) they will suit me I think.

Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I don't know where you got that information from. I've never had such problems whilst using queues and I'm processing data at 1 sec intervals.

Comment: Then they would work fine for this project. Just out of curiosity, if the web application where located outside the azure environment what can be used?

Comment: Yes. You can use any component of Azure of its own just fine. You can even use just queue, and have both web and workers somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Save the XML to the blob storage
2. Use Azure Queue - web app will add the "job" message pointing to XML (XML url + maybe some other data) and worker roles periodically check for "jobs" in this queue and processing them

It is recommended practice in Azure, and it works very well (I am using it on some projects with very high load - hundreds of thousands "jobs" per day. Azure queues are very reliable and fast, those performance issues you have read about were certainly in some "user code".